# Can python script somehow create new console window while running?

Tags: python, console

I write a bot for use by many people. Initially, the bot was not automated, and when somebody asked me to start it for himself, I opened the console window and ran it as “python main.py”. And, therefore, for other people I also should have opened new window and run it for them.

Now, I created platform, where user can register his account and, by specific command, run it for himself without my help.

But I realized that this platform also runs in one console, and when several people click “run bot”, all this happens in one window, although it requires two windows for two people and so on.

So when somebody clicks “run bot”, this platform needs to open new console window, run bot in this window, and after bot’s session, this window needs to be closed.

My question is how can my script perform this action?
I mean how main script can open new window, then run another script in new window, and after session of new script, main script should close new window?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, and I’m running it on python3.7

Upd: I don’t think terminal will help.
When I will deploy my platform on server, there won’t be any programs like terminal etc. I need other solution to do this

Comment: If you are using terminator, you can try `terminator -e "bash -c -l 'python main.py' "`

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven’t tried terminator so far. thanks, I will try this in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

```
cmd2 = "python3.7 /home/dlenskyi/Desktop/test.py " + str(var)
for s in sys.argv[1:]:
    cmd2 += " " + s

subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "-e", cmd2])
```